# Помогите переписать $.ajax в fetch

Tags: javascript

```
let data = {
            'qty': value,
            'isAjax': 1,
            'product': id
           }
```

Это надо переписать

```
 $.ajax({
         url: linkAdd,
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'post',
         data: $.param(data)
     })
```

Я пробовал написать

```
fetch(linkAdd,{
      method: 'POST',
      format: 'json',
      headers: {
               Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: Object.entries(data).map(([key, val])=>`${key}=${val}`).join("&")
    })
```

Почему то разный статус приходить у fetch : Status Code: 302 Found
$.ajax все ок 200

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'`

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)`. Зачем усложнять